# Spring OAuth2 Auth Server: a specific /oauth/token filter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-oauth2

I am currently checking all the incoming `Authorization` headers for JWT token values so that I can check if those tokens are blacklisted. I have implemented a custom `Filter` for this.

The problem is that this filter is handling all the requests that are coming into the server. I'd like to handle only the requests that are coming to the `/oauth/token` endpoint.

Is it possible to implement that in Spring OAuth2 Auth Server?

Comment: Are you a resource or an authorization server?

Comment: @JoseMartinez for auth server.

Comment: And when you say "filter out" does that mean you want your Filter to ignore requests to '/oauth/token' or those are the ones you trying to block?

Comment: @JoseMartinez sorry, I phrased it incorrectly. I want to handle only the requests that are incoming to `oauth/token endpoint`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two aspects to your question, one is Filter order and two is only filtering a specific URL path.  Both can be tackled by using a `FilterRegistrationBean` to inject your filter.  See example below.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean securityFilter() {
    Filter f = new MySecurityFilter();
    FilterRegistrationBean frb = new FilterRegistrationBean(f);
    frb.setOrder(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER);
    frb.setUrlPatterns(Arrays.asList("/oauth/token"));
    return frb;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a question of priority of your filter.
Add :

```
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
```

To your WebSecurityConfiguration should help you.

Answer (score 1):

In the case your custom filter extends the `OncePerRequestFilter` you can override the `shouldNotFilter` method.

```
@Override
protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
    return !new AntPathMatcher().match("/oauth/token", request.getServletPath());
}
```

From the Doc

> Can be overridden in subclasses for custom filtering control, returning true to avoid filtering of the given request.

Comment: The custom filter itself is implementing the `Filter` interface.